# after generating images from microsoft glee graph is there anyway to get the inputs to an image map

Tags: graphing, microsoft-glee

i am taking microsoft glee code and producing a graph and then converting it to an image on an html page.  i want to see if i can autogenerate image map code over the image so i am able to click on each element of the graph nodes.

Here is an example of the glee graph code converting to an image.

```
   Graph g = new Graph("graph");
        g.GraphAttr.LayerDirection = LayerDirection.LR;
        g.GraphAttr.NodeAttr.Padding = 3;

        [Add a bunch of nodes . . .]

        GraphRenderer renderer = new GraphRenderer(g);
        renderer.CalculateLayout();

        //Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(g.Width), Convert.ToInt32(g.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(g.Width), Convert.ToInt32(g.Height),
                                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        renderer.Render(bmp);
```

So the question is:  is there a way to get all of the info that would be needed for an html image map from the glee graph object or the renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Mindscape's WPF Star Diagrams](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/wpfstardiagrams/default.aspx) or [WPF Flow Diagrams](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/wpfflowdiagrams/default.aspx). They make this task much simpler and they look great!